# Facing unexpected result while using pre tag

Tags: html

The output of strike tag is shifted a little towards left (and here it is shifted towards a little right)

```html
 <pre>
 <strong>This text is strong</strong>
 <b>This text is bold</b>
 <i>this text is italised</i>
 <em title="emphasised" style="color:red;">this text is 
        emphasised</em>
 <strike>this text is striked</strike>
 <del>this text is deleted</del>
</pre>
```

The striked text must be just below the emphasised text.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know if your sample HTML should be copied verbatim or not. E.g. should the content of `<em>` be broken into two lines? Should `<strike>` be shifted to the right, or should it be aligned with both `<em>` and `<del>`? Because when I aligned them in source, it works in my browser (Vivaldi).

Comment: Could you add a screenshot documenting the shift?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` tags display content exactly as it is entered within the tag. So all the whitespace and line breaks will be preserved when it is rendered.

It's shifted left because you have whitespace inside the `<pre>` tag.

Remove the any unwanted whitespace and line breaks and everything will line up.

```html
<pre>
<strong>This text is strong</strong>
<b>This text is bold</b>
<i>this text is italised</i>
<em title="emphasised" style="color:red;">this text is emphasised</em>
<strike>this text is striked</strike>
<del>this text is deleted</del>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's just an optical illusion, because strike-trough line touches character box.

Your snippet with reference text and emphasized text line boxes:

```css
pre * {
 background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>
      <strong>This text is strong</strong>
      <b>This text is bold</b>
      <i>this text is italised</i>
      <em title="emphasised" style="color:red;">this text is 
      emphasised</em>
      <span>this text is not striked</span>
      <strike>this text is striked</strike>
      <span>this text is not striked</span>
      <del>this text is deleted</del>
      <span>this text is not striked</span>
</pre>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of above snippet, Firefox, Windows]